# Track mouse input source in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, mouse

I don't remember when it first started but I have an extremely annoying issue where my mouse cursor will randomly jump to different places on the screen (most often, but not always, the very corners of the screen) when I'm moving the mouse.

I've investigated a number of different possibilities, checked the mouse drivers, even uninstalled my antivirus (which added its own driver into the mouse device in device manager), and disabled every non-essential service or "gaming" service (e.g. Logitech's software for managing its hardware), and also disabled the extra virtual mouse devices that are added by both Razer and by Logitech (not sure why Razer adds a virtual mouse since I only have a keyboard from them) but it still happens. I've also disabled TeamViewer and I disabled and stopped Synergy, too, and I don't have any similar software installed. This is on a desktop, not a laptop (no touchscreen). This is a Logitech G502 mouse.

I've run out of ideas to try and things to disable. I was hoping that maybe the Windows API exposed something that said, "The mouse cursor was set to position X,Y because process Z made the Win32 API call to do that." Then I could look at process Z to investigate deeper. Any ideas if that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else comes across this, it turned out that my old Dell mousepad was apparently just too shiny/reflective. The particular style of it was just apparently just screwing with the laser. The moment I stopped using that mousepad, everything was fine.